# Иконка для подключение пароля

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как подключить свою иконку для смены пароля через EditText или для этого придеться использовать TextInputLayout? Если можно через EditText

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что не так с TextInputLayout? Там можно настроить через app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/my_drawable"

Answer (score 1):

Например, так

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_password"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
```

или программно

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
// Set drawables for left, top, right, and bottom - send 0 for nothing
editTxt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.myDrawable, 0, 0, 0);
```